# Email Template Button Marketo — Forcing it's styles to be inherited by the Module below

Tags: html, html-email, email, marketo

I have a button module I've made for Marketo. It checks out fine, but once I integrate it with my template and place a module below it — the module below it not only inherits the buttons styles (associated with type, ie. size, uppercase, bold) but also gains a little width too and aligns left. The button module stays uneffected — yet whatever is below it gets messed with. I can't figure out what is doing this in the buttons code because it looks clean to me.

Not sure if anyone can help, but take a look at my button code and let me know if you see anything unusual.

```html
<tr class="mktoModule" id="oneButton" mktoName="One Button Module" mktoAddByDefault="false">
            <td align="center">
                <table width="600" align="center" valign="middle" class="breakpoints" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin:0 auto;width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding:30px 0px 37px 0px;">
                            <table width="100%" align="center">
                                <tr align="center">
                                    <td>
                                        <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr align="center ">
                                                <td align="center " style="padding-bottom:0; " valign="top">
                                                    <table align="center " border="0 " cellpadding="0 " cellspacing="0 " style="width:270px;border-collapse:separate;background-color:#FDB71A;border-radius:3px; ">
                                                        <tr align="center ">
                                                            <td class="mktoText" mktoName="Button — First CTA — Yellow" id="button-first-cta-single" align="center " height="45 " style="text-align:center;height:45px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;" valign="middle "><a href="# " style="padding:10px 20px;display:inline-block;font-family: Arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;line-height:26px; ">CTA Button</a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you integrating the new module (are you coding it in or are you dragging it in via wisiwyg?

There are a lot of td sections in here so I'm wondering if it's possible that this is sitting in the One Button Module tr by mistake?

Comment: Ask questions in comments please.